# image not aligning with right side of the div

Tags: html, css, image

I have problem aligning the image to the right side of the div with no margin or padding and image should be flushed right with the right border of the div. I tried everything I knew but didn't work. Hopefully someone has a solution for this problem for me. Thanks
Here is the code

HTML

```
  <div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://city.kermanemajazi.ir/i/attachments/1/1413914460279666_large.jpg" alt="Image" id="image">
  <h2> Heading </h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id quisquam           fugit maxime repellat corporis ipsa, a placeat! Nihil commodi asperiores   reiciendis provident laboriosam, sit error!
  </p>
  <a href="#"> Learn More </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body
{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.col-1-3
{
width: 320px;
border: 1px solid red;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;

}

.clip
{
 padding-right: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

Here is the jsbin link for the example code
[JsBin Example Code](http://jsbin.com/muxidecofi/edit?html,css,output) 
Thanks

Comment: Can't you simply float the image to the right?

Comment: If you image width is filling up the entire container width anyway, floating it doesn't change anything. You need to set it to a width narrower than its containing parent to see the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this to your CSS

```
.clip img {
  float: right;
}
```

Here's the documentation about floats in css: **[float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)**

Your updated script: **[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/muxidecofi/1/edit?html,css,output)**

Comment: Thanks guys, it helped. Patrick2607 can you please tell that why the column in the middle just popping down a bit than other two ?

Comment: Take a look at the link about floats I provided. To solve your problem, add this to your css: h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: There is a function for that ;), on the left side of my post/solution there is an up/down button and a checkmark. Pressing this will show other users who have this problem what the solution was.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `float:right;` in your `.clip` of css
Here is updated example
[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/nafocufipo/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Here is the link for actualy three colum layout in which image in the first colum is needed left aligned and the image of third colum right aligned.http://jsbin.com/muxidecofi/edit?css,output